# How can I solve stationarity after already having applied differentiation and log?

Tags: time-series, stationarity, acf-pacf

Here's the thing, I'm not 100% sure if this is a stationarity problem or if I'm missing something, or even if this is an issue in a real world dataset.

I applied log and differentiation to my time-series dataset. After that, I plotted the ACF and PACF graph, just like any course tells us to do. Look at the graphs:

[image]

[image]

AD-Fuller tells me the data is stationary. But the graphs are weird and I'm not even sure if I should apply any other transformations or if my models will work (I don't think so because I've tried a few things).

Any ideas on this issue? Should I be worried about these plots? Are there other transformations I should apply?

Comment: How long is your series?  Ordinarily looking 80+ lags out is almost meaningless and is a rather unstable procedure unless the series is much longer than $2\times 80=160$ steps.

Comment: The data is grouped by week, I have 158 weeks. Should I just ignore what happens in PACF after the 80th lag?

Comment: Yes.  You might have a tiny bit of interest in the PACF at 13, 26, and 52 weeks in case there is strong seasonality (the ACF itself has an interesting spike at 52 weeks), but otherwise only the first few lags really matter.

Comment: You can try KPSS and see if that tells you anything.

Comment: Also, be careful when interpreting ACF and PACF plots after having applied differencing. It is expected to have some spurious peaks in the lags that you applied differentiation